# Susy Import Failing in Dart Project

Tags: sass, dart, rubymine, compass, susy

I'm setting up a standalone Dart project in Rubymine that uses sass/compass/susy. The main scss file is from a Ruby on Rails project. In it I have

```
@import "compass";
@import 'susy';
```

When I do a build, it's happy with the compass import but not susy. I get the error:

```
[Error from Sass on jazzcat|lib/css/master.scss]:
could not resolve import 'Instance of '_SassImport'' (tried [jazzcat|lib/css/susy.scss, jazzcat|lib/css/susy.sass, jazzcat|lib/css/_susy.scss, jazzcat|lib/css/_susy.sass])
```

I've never had to load susy code to a project before. Do I need to add something to my pubspec? This is what I have now:

```
name: jazzcat
description: A catalog of jazz music
version: 0.0.1
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.13.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular2: 2.0.0-beta.17
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
  sass: any
transformers:
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES'
    platform_pipes:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
    entry_points: web/main.dart
- sass:
      compass: true                 # Include compass
      line-numbers: true            # Include line numbers in output
      style: compact                # Style of generated CSS
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

Comment: I gave up on trying to fix this on my own. Instead, I moved the project to PHPStorm and use the file watcher facility to run compass when needed. I keep checking back for an answer to this problem.